# Why nothing happens if I return EXIT_FAILURE at the end of my main function entry point in my program?

Tags: c++

There are two macros in C++ that represent a number to return in the last line of your entry point. `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS`. If I return `EXIT_FAILURE`, which is 1, absolutely nothing happens. I explicitly wrote that the exit of my program was not successful, why is nothing happening?

Comment: Do you mean `int main() { ...; return EXIT_FAILURE; }`?

Comment: What does "nothing happens" means?

Comment: Yes, I mean `int main() { ...; return EXIT_FAILURE; }` :)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I mean nothing shows in output at the time of executing my compiled program

Comment: If you want to "see something happen", try throwing [an uncaught exception](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_023.html) and get more crash-y behavior.

Comment: What led you to believe that a non-zero exit code must result in some kind of an output?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik because I did read "FAILURE" and in my head the word failure programmatically and automatically means "ERROR! EXCEPTION!"

Comment: Yes, well, as it has been mentioned, this is just the means for the process to return a numeric status code to the parent process. Whether or not the parent process announces something is up to the parent process. The `bash` shell does not, but I dimly recall that old `csh` shells, and derivatives, did announce non-0 exit codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return code from your process has absolutely no effect on your process. It's only for the parent process which initiated your process to know how your run turned out.

The parent process is often the shell, though it could be any other mechanism that made the `exec` (or equivalent) call. Your `EXIT_FAILURE` indicates to the parent process that something went wrong.

For example, on the shell:

```sh
./myprog || echo "Uh oh"
```

Where the "Uh oh" part is only shown if the process does not return `EXIT_SUCCESS` (`0`).

A well-behaved program often logs *why* it had a problem, and it does it specifically to `STDERR`. This helps differentiate expected output from error output. This is not done for you automatically. This is entirely your responsibility.

Comment: This. Presumably "nothing" happens because OP isn't checking the return code and doing "something."